# Iterate on shuffled cartesian product in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cartesian-product

I would like to iterate on a shuffled cartesian product.

In python, I can do:

```
import itertools
import random

size = 10
pts = [pt for pt in itertools.product(range(size), range(size), range(size))]
random.shuffle(pts)
print pts
```

If size increase or if I need higher dimension, this approach can consume too much memory.

In Haskell, do you know if it is possible to do this by using lazy evaluation or some other magical stuff ?

Thanks for your help

Olivier

Comment: I don't see how lazy evaluation can help here.   In order to shuffle a sequence you must evaluate all the "spine" of the sequence to generate a true random sequence (otherwise you'd be limited to random sampling of a prefix), so you have a problem with the space in any case.   The  only way I can think of would be to "number" all possible permutations. Then instead of shuffling you generate a random number between `1` and `n!`. And have a function that given the permutation number and an index retrieves the element from that permutation. However retrieving becomes inefficient.

Comment: What value of `size` do you want to use? And do you need the entire list?

Comment: You can avoid allocating the initial list, by using the function @Bakuriu suggests. But what I don't think you can avoid is the fact that to produce the next element in the shuffle of `n` elements, you must *somehow* remember which elements you have already seen, which takes `n` bits by the "obvious" method, and optimally only a handful less when you're about halfway in the list.

Comment: Besides: lazy evaluation is not magical (if it were your problem would be solved trivially in some way...). What you don't pay in time (e.g. avoid evalution of something) you pay it in space (e.g. big thunks). But this is a general rule in complexity: you often can use more space to reduce the time taken, or save in space by using more time. In this case either you use O(n) space to shuffle or you can use O(logn) space but you increase time to something like O(n^2) (like O(n) for each access in general).

Comment: @Bakuriu Oh you *can* use O(log n) space? Hm now that I think about it, a logspace version of `sort . zip (randoms g)` should work...

Comment: @Bakuriu Alas, that idea was O(n^3) time. Now I also see how to do it in O(log n) space and O(n^2) time, to look up a single element you run Fisher-Yates backwards on the whole list, ignoring what happens to any elements except the one you're looking up...